# Undoable rename

Tags: rename

I have a large number of files (specifically, my music collection) that I plan to rename (using Ex Falso).

I have the files backed up, so in principle I can restore if necessary, but that would be time consuming.

It seems to me that using hard linking, I should be able to make a backup copy that I could restore very easily, should I make a mistake in my renaming attempt.

Can anyone suggest how this might be done most easily?

Comment: On GNU systems, there's `cp -rl`. POSIXly, there's `pax`. `cpio` can also do.